# Chemfig: Modify bond offset on just one end of a bond

Tags: spacing, chemfig, alignment

I need a litte bit of help with an unforgiving permanganate ion. More specifically, it's about the Mn-O-bonds protruding into the Mn-atoms bounding (?) box.

Now, I know chemfig provides an option with which you can modify only the offset on a single side of a bond, and I know how to use it - I thought. However, the stupid thing does not want to cooperate inside of a reaction scheme; it spits out errors.

This is what I already have: A pretty much wonderful permanganate ion, with all the bonds properly aligned.

[image: How it should be]

This is the corresponding code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{Mn(=#(4pt)[1]O)(=#(4pt)[3]O)(=#(4pt)[5]O)(-#(4pt)[7]\charge{45:1pt=-}{O})}

\end{document}
```

However, once I put this into a reaction scheme environment, I'm getting an error: Illegal parameter number. And if I leave away all the #(xpt,ypt) stuff, my bonds weird out on me:

[image: This is ugly]

Corresponding code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{Mn(=[1]O)(=[3]O)(=[5]O)(-[7]\charge{45:1pt=-}{O})}
\arrow
Stuff
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing something wrong? Is this feature not supposed to work in a reaction scheme? I'm very sure there's gotta be a solution to this, considering how simple a stupid permanganate ion really is. Propably I'm running a totally wrong approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `#` token, you can use tge `chemfig style` key:

```
\chemfig[chemfig style={shorten <=4pt}]{Mn(=[1]O)(=[3]O)(=[5]O)(-[7]\charge{45:1pt=-}{O})}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!